# После загрузки данных Ajax'ом отображает только последнее значение

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть таблица, в ней много ячеек. Хочу Ajax'ом лениво выдергивать значения из базы и по готовности вставлять.

При первом обходе и рисовании таблицы на PHP собираю массив ID для дальнейшей отправки Ajax'ом.

Но отображаются данные только в последней ячейке:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //console.log(array);
    var path = '<?php echo $path; ?>'; //путь к контролеру
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var elem = array[i];
        var url = path + "ajaxAll?val=" + encodeURIComponent(elem);
        console.log(elem, url);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                //alert ($id);
                document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML = data; //запись в ячейку
            }
        })
        // document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML = elem; //так нормально пишет в нужную ячейку
    }
```

---

пример array

> ["37_2015-06-1_1_2", "38_2015-06-1_1_2", "39_2015-06-1_1_2",
>   "58_2015-06-1_1_2", "62_2015-06-1_1_2", "66_2015-06-1_1_2",
>   "37_2015-06-2_1_2", "38_2015-06-2_1_2", "39_2015-06-2_1_2"]

то есть ид все есть. да и `document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML = elem;` нормально данные вставляет

innerHTML += записал все ответы в одну последнюю ячейку. то есть ajax запрос идет, а вот ид он берет последний
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы в отправляемом ответе сервера указывайте идентификатор ячейки/запроса, чтобы js знал, что в ответ то пришло.

Comment: не знал таких нюансов. можно подробнее

Comment: @Visman а зачем указать идентификатор в ответе?

Comment: @Regent, если для заполнения каждой ячейки делается свой ajax запрос, то как узнать куда вставлять ответ? Вот и советую указывать идентификатор ячейки.

Comment: @Visman вставлять в `elem`. По-моему, проблема в этой строке: `var elem = array[i];`. В `success` `elem` всегда указывает на последний элемент массива. Сравните [вариант через функцию](http://jsfiddle.net/5m9veyb0/1/) и [исходный вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/5m9veyb0/2/).

Comment: @Regent, видимо я не внимательно прочитал вопрос.

Comment: @des1roer "> UPD: не оч понимаю как применить..." весь метод ajax внутрь функции поместите, а то кусок $.ajax({ снаружи остался и пропала закрывающая скобка вроде. ;) Ну или как в моем примере.

Comment: да я со скобками запоролся. разобрался. все работает. https://gist.github.com/des1roer/7488e68e4f81564c3cf5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Хотите я Вам фокус покажу?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var elem = i;
    window.setTimeout(function(){ console.log(elem) },1000);
}
```

Вы думаете данный код вернет последовательность от 0 до 9? А вот и не угадали, он вернет Вам десять раз девятку. точно так же, как ваш код вставит все данные в только в конечный elem, а не по последовательности. Это связанно с областями видимости, да данный момент возникает замыкание на внешний контекст.

Спасибо @Regent за подсказку, код можно изменить так, обернув функцию и разорвав замыкание:

```
success: (function (elem){ return function(data) {
    document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML = data; 
}})(elem)
```

Comment: Как вариант: [мой код из комментария](http://jsfiddle.net/5m9veyb0/1/).

Comment: @Regent, ну да, все правильно, изменить видимость для переменной передав ее в другую функцию тем самым разорвав замыкание.

Comment: вот про это я и не знал. спасибо огромное. правда уж по совету @Visman решил возвращать ид элемента вместе со значением. но у вас я думаю правильней будет

Answer (score 0):

Лучше изменить метод так, чтобы он возвращал все необходимые значения сразу. 100 ajax запросов от каждого пользователя может создать значительную нагрузку для сервер.

**UPD:**

В примере elem объявлен в замыкании, после ответа сервера значение elem будет последним (т. е. elem = array[array.length - 1] для каждого ответа). Чтоб избежать этого можно использовать $.proxy

```
...
success: $.proxy(function(data){
    $(this).append(data);
}, elem)
...
```

В данном случае this будет указывать на elem

Comment: целостные данные отдать проблематично. там запрос усложняется в экспоненциальном порядке. мне в принципе гарантия порядка запросов не важна. хотя и она вроде как обеспечивается обходом массива.